# Text cursor invisible in gedit for dark desktop theme

Tags: 20.04, themes, gedit

Gedit was working fine with the default desktop theme in Ubuntu 20.04.
However, when I changed the desktop theme to dark, the text cursor in gedit becomes invisible, although the functionality of the editor is not hindered.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Go to the Preferences menu on Gedit and change the Color Scheme on Fonts & Colors tab.
Check if the text is readable even with the presence of the highlighted content on the selected line.

Comment: Tried that. Indeed, there are color schemes that reveal the text cursor, both dark and light, such as Solarized. However, I would like to use Kate color scheme for gedit while in the dark theme for the desktop. So, this does not solve my problem, unfortunately.

Comment: I see. Sorry for not being able to answer your question. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Late but it worked for me. I also like to use the "Kate" scheme. So here is what I did.

- Select the "Kate" scheme in prefences.
- Open then color scheme editor from the gedit menu.
- Change the "Name" and the "ID" field i.e "KateN" and "kateN"
- Locate the "cursor" entry, 4. from top, in the left list box and select it.
- The click the foreground checkbox and select the black color
- Click on "Save" button.
- Done

The new scheme "KateN" will be saved under  "~/.local/share/gedit/styles/kateN.xml"

Comment: @Kilroy "color scheme editor" is not in the menu, neither I can see a plugin with a similar name.